# Unable to run pgadmin4 docker on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

*Hello StackOverflowers,*

I am trying to install `pgadmin4` using `Docker` in `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`, but each time I create a container it crashes.

Here is the command i use:

```
docker run -p 8082:80 --name pgadmin_server \
-e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@domain.com' \
-e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password' \
 dpage/pgadmin4
```

Here is the result i get

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

When i run `docker container ls -a`, this is what i get. My container has been shutdown

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES
034b89accaae        dpage/pgadmin4      "/entrypoint.sh"         5 minutes ago       Exited (1) 4 minutes ago                            pgadmin_server
1e660903663e        postgres:9.2        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 minutes ago      Up 48 minutes              0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   postgres_container
```

And here is the docker version i use:

```
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
```

Btw, I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on 32 bit machine

*Thank you for your help*

Comment: There's a good chance that the `dpage/pgadmin4` image -- and most other images -- are only built for 64 bit platforms.

Comment: @larsks Please, Do you know how to tell if an image is built for 64bit architecture or also the 32 one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build an image locally, it will by default be built for the same architecture as your local host. Since most x86 systems these days are 64 bit systems (to the point that many distributions have dropped support for the 32 bit x86 architecture), that means that the vast majority of images you find will only run on x86_64 systems.

It's more common to find multiarch support in "official" images:

> Most of the official images on Docker Hub provide a variety of architectures. For example, the busybox image supports amd64, arm32v5, arm32v6, arm32v7, arm64v8, i386, ppc64le, and s390x. When running this image on an x86_64 / amd64 machine, the x86_64 variant will be pulled and run.

(That quote is from the following link)

While there is [support for building multi-architecture images](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/multi-arch/), that requires explicit configuration by the person building the image.

I don't believe that Docker provides any tools for conveniently exploring the supported architecture for a given image. You can use the [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) tool to do this, although the process is still a little non-obvious. To see the list of architecture for a multi-architecture image, we need to use the `--raw` option:

```
$ skopeo inspect --raw docker://busybox | python -mjson.tool | grep -i architecture
                "architecture": "amd64",
                "architecture": "arm",
                "architecture": "arm",
                "architecture": "arm",
                "architecture": "arm64",
                "architecture": "386",
                "architecture": "mips64le",
                "architecture": "ppc64le",
                "architecture": "s390x",
```

For single architecture images, the above will yield no results; in that case, drop the `--raw` to see the architecture:

```
$ skopeo inspect docker://dpage/pgadmin4 | python -mjson.tool | grep -i architecture
    "Architecture": "amd64",
```

Comment: Thank you for those insights. Effectively the image i am using doesn't support the 32bit architecture. I tried it in a 64bit and it worked just fine.